# Unable to launch external script from Matlab: Permission Denied

Tags: matlab, administrator

I have this problem: I'm trying to launch an external code from Matlab in Mac using the "System" command. When I launch it, it returns the error: Permission Denied. 
How can I run the code in "sudo mode" as administrator?
If I add the sudo command before launching the code, it asks the password, but it is impossible to add it in Matlab.
Tank you very much

Comment: Why not run MATLAB with `sudo` in the first place? Wouldn't that automatically elevate all commands coming from it...?

Comment: it might be a better option to change the permissions on the external code, `$ chmod 777 path/to/file` to allow matlab to execute it

Comment: @Dev-iL using `sudo` directly to call an application with a GUI can mess up permissions of files related to X in one's home directory. It's safer to use `gksu` in this case, I believe.

Comment: What is gksu? Isn't there any change I can do in the matlab script to call the application?

Comment: I cannot touch the application code. I can just change the matlab code